# How to pass string parameter in innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am creating dynamic html base server response.

Example:

```
var responseServer = {
name: "al the' too"
}

var htmlView = `<div onclick="info(responseServer.name)"> </div>`; 
//Error: al identifier is not defined. 

var htmlView = `<div onclick="info('responseServer.name')"> </div>`; 
//Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

After construction html i am getting following code :

```js
function info(name){
 alert(name);
}
```

```html
<div>
<button onclick="info('al al'the ra)">
  Test
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The first syntax seems ok. The error `al identifier is not defined` means its some error inside info function.

Comment: info function is not called

Comment: How are you adding the htmlView to your page? If its not using the dom methods then the onclick event handler might not be attached and it will be just like a text lying there.

Comment: I think you please add more code here so that we can see the context, can you create some stackblitz etc to show what it is?

Comment: yes sure add more code

Comment: let me Tim567 answer

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari, that's not work, After transpile to typescript and minimify, the function "info" will has another name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got workaround as follow:

```js
function info(name){
 alert(atob(name));
}

var sName = "al al'the ra";

var myHtml = document.getElementById("one");
myHtml.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<button onclick=info(btoa(sName))> Test </button>");
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
```

This is not actual build and runtime environment. I have use this work around in ionic 3 with angular.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a simple snippet fot this:

```js
var responseServer = {
  name: "al the' too"
}

function info(str){
  console.log(str)
}
```

```html
<div onclick=info(responseServer.name)>Click me!</div>
```

You can see it works fine. So as @muasif80 pointet out it has to do with the `info()` function!

---

**Edit**

If I add the div with `onclick()` event dynamicly it still works:

```js
$('body').append('<div onclick=info(responseServer.name)>Click me!</div>');

var responseServer = {
  name: "al the' too"
}

function info(str){
  console.log(str)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: info function not executing and i am generating html in javascript

Comment: Are you sure the `info()` function is identefied? @KhurshidAnsari

Comment: let me try please

Comment: I am generating hmtl dynamic

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari I'm now adding it dynamic but I still don't have anny issues.... Can you try re repeduce the issue in your question?

Answer (score 1):

The code is working. You need to enclose function inside onclick in quotes. Please check snippet

```js
function streetInfoSinage(name){
          alert(name)
          }
          var name = "Al Ma'mourah St";
          
function createDom(){
  let responseServer = {
    name: "al the' too"
  };
  
  
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = "Hello World " + responseServer.name;
  div.addEventListener("click", function(){info(responseServer.name)});
  document.getElementById("my-dom").appendChild(div);
}

function info(name){
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<p style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;" onclick='streetInfoSinage("Razeen St")'>
            Razeen St &nbsp; <i style="font-size: 14px;" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
          </p>
          
<div id="my-dom">
</div>

<button onclick="createDom()">call info</div>
```

I have updated the snippet to to give another example

Comment: This is **not** what he is trying try reading comments on other answers...

Comment: You can change according to your needs i have updated the snippet to add another example